# JSON Data Get list of common data : Jquery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to know how many website in MY JSON Data

```
[{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A4298","website":"google"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A2222","website":"google"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41Awww33","website":"yahoo"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A424448","website":"google"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429rr8","website":"ebay"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429ff8","website":"ebay"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429ss8","website":"rediff"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429sg8","website":"yahoo"}]
```

I want to output like

```
var webList="google,yahoo,ebay,rediff";
```

**OR**

```
webList[0]="google";
webList[1]="yahoo";
webList[2]="ebay";
webList[3]="rediff";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need remove the duplicate check the array before push with [$.inArray](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray/):

```
var data=[{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A4298","website":"google"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A2222","website":"google"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41Awww33","website":"yahoo"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A424448","website":"google"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429rr8","website":"ebay"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429ff8","website":"ebay"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429ss8","website":"rediff"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429sg8","website":"yahoo"}];

var webList = new Array();
$.each(data,function(index,item){
if ($.inArray(item.website, webList)==-1) {
         webList.push(item.website);
    }
});
console.log(webList);
```

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TCF3e/)

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you want:

```
var data=[{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A4298","website":"google"},
          {"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A2222","website":"google"},
          {"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41Awww33","website":"yahoo"},
          {"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A424448","website":"google"},
          {"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429rr8","website":"ebay"},
          {"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429ff8","website":"ebay"},
          {"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429ss8","website":"rediff"},
          {"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429sg8","website":"yahoo"}];

var webList = new Array();

$.each(data,function(index,item){

    if($.inArray(item.website, webList) == -1)
      webList.push(item.website);

    console.log(webList);

})
```

you can access this way the item you want or iterate like i did on json array:

```
console.log(webList[0]);
```

[**Fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/aT67C/2/)

Comment: Ehsan I want one website name only one time ...not repeated  ..your console output : google,google,yahoo,google,ebay,ebay,rediff,yahoo

Comment: you have to filter from array at end

Answer (score 1):

You could do it this way:

http://jsfiddle.net/DianaNassar/C97DJ/1/

```
var data = [{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A4298","website":"google"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A2222","website":"google"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41Awww33","website":"yahoo"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A424448","website":"google"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429rr8","website":"ebay"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429ff8","website":"ebay"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429ss8","website":"rediff"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429sg8","website":"yahoo"}];

var uniqueNames = [];
for(i = 0; i< data.length; i++){    
    if(uniqueNames.indexOf(data[i].website) === -1){
        uniqueNames.push(data[i].website);        
    }        
}

for(i = 0; i< uniqueNames.length; i++){    
    alert(uniqueNames[i]);      
}
```